# HashSet в Java - почему добавляются одинаковые объекты, хотя не должны?

Tags: java, hashset

В Java совсем недавно и появилась проблема с добавлением элементов в HashSet. Я хочу создать множество из своего типа данных Model, HashSet. По принципам работы множества одинаковых элементов там быть не должно, но полностью одинаковые объекты добавляются без проблем. Делаю простую проверку:

```
if (_hs.add(model))
```

и она всегда проходит. Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Вы в своем классе `Model` переопределили методы `equals()` и `hashCode()`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, направили, куда надо гуглить ! Да, этого и не хватало, теперь все работает как положено !

Comment: @Nofate, думаю, это можно и в ответ написать)

Comment: @Nofate имхо тут бы хорошо ответом оформить, ибо вопрос по основам хороший

Comment: @rjhdby по многочисленным просьбам, опубликовал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для корректной работы `HashSet`, `HashMap` и других структур данных, полагающихся на хэши объектов, при их сравнении обязательно нужно переопределять методы `Object.equals()` и `Object.hashCode()`.

Не забывайте, что `equals()` должен гарантировать:

- `x.equals(x) == true` для всего, кроме null;
- `если x.equals(y) == true`, то и `y.equals(x) == true` для всего, кроме null;
- если `x.equals(y) == true` и `y.equals(z) == true`, то `x.equals(z) == true` для всего, кроме null;
- `x.equals(y)` для конкретной пары ссылок всегда возвращает одно и то же значение, если их состояние не менялось;
- для ненулевого `x` сравнение с `null` должно возвращать `false`.

Кроме того, от `hashCode()` ожидается, что:

- при вызове на одном и том же объекте будут возвращаться одинаковые значения, если не менялись значения полей, использующихся в методе `equals`;
- если `x.equals(y) == true`, то `x.hashCode() == y.hashCode()`;
- если `x.equals(y) != true`, то результат `hashCode()` не обязан быть разным (однако, это будет влиять на производительность структур данных, полагающихся на `hashCode()`).

Если вы не хотите вдаваться в тонкости получения хэша от объекта, достаточно воспользоваться средствами IDE для генерации методов `equals` и `hashCode`, выбрав поля, которые важны для логического равенства объектов.